# PHP unexpected T_FUNCTION/construct issue?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have code in cake php that looks like:

```
public $ceff_instance = array();

public function __construct() {

    $this->ceff_instance = $this->wsMethod_GO();
}

protected $filedMethodMappings = $this->$ceff_instance;
```

Where `$wsMethod_GO` returns an array. However, it says that there is an `unexpected T_FUNCTION` on the line where I try to put the `$ceff_instance` array into `$filedMethodMappings`. What is the reason for this?

I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected $filedMethodMappings = $this->$ceff_instance;
```

You can't set use `$this` outside of methods.

```
public $ceff_instance = array();
protected $filedMethodMappings = NULL;

public function __construct() {
    $this->ceff_instance = $this->wsMethod_GO();
    $this->filedMethodMappings = $this->$ceff_instance;
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/1V6ChkY0

Comment: @Sarfraz: Thanks :-)  Though I should probably get back to work :-P